# How to adjust Vuetify components dimensions?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a project that includes text fields, buttons and a certain form design. I'm using Vuetify to achieve this but there's one problem that I'm not sure how to handle: Vuetify components dimensions seemed not changable.

For example :

[image]

I want `v-text-field`, `v-select` and `v-btn` to have the same height and `<v-select>` to be a bit wide relative to the button.

Is there a way to achieve this in Vuetify ? Or is it handled by CSS superimposition ?

Comment: Put your vuetify widgets in flex-box divs, and use the flex property to set their widths.

Comment: can you show an example ?

Comment: you can use [grid] (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#usage) system of vuetify to achieve your result

Comment: i posted a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using `flexbox` to keep items in a row, with one child taking up all the remaining space.  Flexbox has a nice ability to override the child width and give you predictable results.

```html
<div style='display:flex'>

<div style='flex:0 0 auto'>Item 1</div>
<div style='flex:1; background-color: yellow'>Item 2</div>
<div style='flex:0 0 auto'>Item 3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in terms of the height, there is a height property for inputs and button
checkout here : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-input/#props-height